# C Array of Struct Initializing

Tags: c

The following code gives me a GCC error for missing braces, but no matter which combinations I try (including just a single value of 0), it does not resolve. Can anyone give some insight?

```
#define NUM_TABLE_ELEMENTS 1

typedef struct parameter_t
{
   struct
   {
      uint8_t     A : 1;
      uint8_t     B : 1;
      uint8_t     C : 1;
      uint8_t     D : 5;      
   } W;                                                          
   uint8_t    X;
   uint8_t    Y;
   uint8_t    Z;
} parameter_t;


parameter_t MyTable[NUM_TABLE_ELEMENTS] =
{
   { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 0, 0, 0 },
};
```

Comment: This compiles fine on ideone with C99 standard setting ([demo](http://ideone.com/0vuMlp)).

Comment: Please post the exact error message and gcc flags.

Comment: error: missing braces around initializer [-Werror=missing-braces]

I realize it's an upgraded warning... I'm anal retentive.

Comment: @SeaNick Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

This is why you don't shortcut the question with things you make assumptions on:

The ACTUAL struct I was using was:

```
typedef struct parameter_t
{
   struct
   {
      uint8_t     A : 1;
      uint8_t     B : 1;
      uint8_t     C : 1;
      uint8_t     D : 5;      
   } W;                                                          
   uint8_t    X;
   uint8_t    Y[1];
   uint8_t    Z[1];
} parameter_t;


parameter_t MyTable[NUM_TABLE_ELEMENTS] =
{
   { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 0, 0, 0 },
};
```

So it was missing braces around the other arrays, even though they were single element... Feel free to downvote me for my slacking.